# Getting path name of a URL then storing it in a variable (php) using htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I am trying configure my htaccess on my root directory such that if a person types:

```
www.example.com/link1/stuff
```

into their browser, 'stuff' will be stored as a variable later on to be used by a PHP file.

I figure that the best way to do it is to redirect it to another url and get the php using php $_GET.

```
www.example.com/link1/file.php?var="stuff"
```

Is there a better way of doing this?

Note:
I would like the link to stay exactly the same as

```
www.example.com/link1/stuff
```

even though it will be redirected.

Comment: The approach you describe is perfectly fine. Actually it is in wide usage. Just don't make an external redirection, rewrite internally. This leaves the visible url as you want it, but allows to map data internally the way you require.

Comment: Just use a `RewriteRule` to point to a PHP script and use `$_SERVER['PATH_INFO']`.

Answer (score 0):

use htaccess

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase www.example.com/

RewriteRule (.*)/(.*)  www.example.com/$1/file.php?var=$2
```

OR

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase www.example.com/

RewriteRule link1/(.*)  www.example.com/link1/file.php?var=$1
```

Answer (score 0):

you don't have to redirect to a different page and pass it as $_GET var. Simply use `parse_url` and access your needed fragment e.g. via:

```
$uri = 'www.example.com/link1/file.php?var="stuff'
$uri = parse_url($uri);

echo $uri['path'] //returns /file
```

http://de3.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php